# Store data temporarily before saving into database

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I am developing an application using Yii framework where I need to store data temporarily before saving into database.

The screen is divided into  master and detail.

The detail part is shown using CGridview.

I want to store the data in CGridview tempoarily and when the save button is clicked it will be stored into database. The temporary data should be editable and can be deleted.

I thought of storing it in session, but then how can I generate new primary key ID for the rows?

Also emptying the table and then inserting all the values in CGridview  into table is not possible, because I am linking those IDs to a history table of the same data.

How can I do this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If framework you are using permits that, I would suggest retrieving (and reserving) the next primary key value from a database before a new row in the slave table view is presented to the user and using it when the row is to be stored in the database (along with other rows referencing master table view row).
To achieve this, you can specify that primary key column should accept values from a particular sequence which will guarantee their uniqueness.

If your table already exists and you don't want to recreate it, one of the ways would be following these steps:

1. Prevent new rows from being inserted into the table before the whole operation is finished.
2. Create a sequence with start value greater than the greatest existing primary key value and associate the sequence with the primary key column, eg.:

   CREATE SEQUENCE foo_id_seq START WITH 1000;
   ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval ( 'foo_id_seq' );
3. Ensure that all new rows take primary key value from that sequence. The next sequence value can be obtained with:

   SELECT nextval ( 'foo_id_seq' );

More in these docs:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

Answer (score -1):

Try like this..
A variable to store your data temp.

```
 _myAttachments = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
```

and attaching the data to the temp variable

```
private void UploadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        if (DataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && DataGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                //Set File dialog properties
                fileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
                fileDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
                fileDialog.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
                fileDialog.Title = "Select a file";
                fileDialog.Multiselect = false;

                if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileDialog.FileName);
                    byte[] binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileDialog.FileName);
                    DataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = fileInfo.Name;

                    if (_myAttachments.ContainsKey(dgvCell.RowIndex))
                        _myAttachments[dgvCell.RowIndex] = binaryData;
                    else
                        _myAttachments.Add(dgvCell.RowIndex, binaryData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using php Yii framework. Also it is not related to file uploading.